# How to get response text even when there is a 301 status?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I've written a script in scrapy to fetch the response text from a webpage. The problem is my script always prints `None` just because there is `301 status`.

***Is there any way I can take control of that status from being 301 and print the response in the console?***

Here is what I've tried:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class ResponseSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "transfermarkt"
    handle_httpstatus_list = [301]
    start_urls = ["https://www.transfermarkt.es/guti/profil/spieler/6079"]

    def parse(self,response):
        print(response.text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = CrawlerProcess({'USER_AGENT':'Mozilla/5.0'})
    c.crawl(ResponseSpider)
    c.start()
```

What it prints currently:

```
2019-04-29 13:39:41 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6024
2019-04-29 13:39:42 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (301) <GET https://www.transfermarkt.es/guti/profil/spieler/6079> (referer: None)

2019-04-29 13:39:43 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2019-04-29 13:39:43 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 220,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 511,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/301': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 29, 7, 39, 43, 50813),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 9,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 29, 7, 39, 41, 869745)}
2019-04-29 13:39:43 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what do you expect. The response actually *is* empty. A 301 status means "moved permanently", there is no content. If you try to download it with a browser, you shall see a response header `location: https://www.transfermarkt.es/zeljko-kalac/profil/spieler/6079` and your browser will automatically follow this link, while your program won't.

Comment: When I try this `res = requests.get(link,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
print(res.text)`, I get usual response so what I wish to do now is get the same using scrapy. As the requests module with a header can do the trick, I suppose there is any way in scrapy to get the respone text handling redirection or something that is happening here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case:
 request to https://www.transfermarkt.es/guti/profil/spieler/6079 (url **A** - 301 response) is redirected to 
https://www.transfermarkt.es/zeljko-kalac/profil/spieler/6079 (url **B** - 200 response)

Scrapy handles redirect 3xx statuses by default using `RedirectMiddleware` ( [docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#module-scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect), [code](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/downloadermiddlewares/redirect.py#L62) )

 To parse webpage **B** you need to simply remove `handle_httpstatus_list = [301]` from your code

On most of cases 301 responses don't contain html code. All relevant data contained in response headers.

 If you need to print relevant data from 301 response of url **A**:

1. Don't delete `handle_httpstatus_list = [301]`
2. Use `response.headers` data instead of `response.text`